# Sending image to Hangouts from local folder

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin.android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm attempting to send an image to Hangouts from within an app I'm building.
I'm working in Xamarin for VS 2015 to do this so the code below is c# but it's not much different from the equivalent Java code so I think it's easy to follow.

What I've done is set up a button on my app which has code setting up an Intent to share an image to Hangouts. I've set the image up already in the Downloads folder on the device and hardcoded the name into the code.

```
Intent hangoutsShareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionSend); 
hangoutsShareIntent.SetType("image/jpeg");
hangoutsShareIntent.SetPackage("com.google.android.talk");

string downloadsPath = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads).AbsolutePath;
string filePath = Path.Combine(downloadsPath, "shared.jpg");

hangoutsShareIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, filePath);
StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(hangoutsShareIntent, "Share with"));
```

When I run this, I get the option to select a chat in Hangouts that I want to send the content to. Upon selecting the chat, I get a blank message box and no image.

I've swapped the above code over to use `text/plain` and pass the `filePath` variable to the message. When I copy the file path into Chrome to check it, the image loads so I have to figure that the image is where I've said it is... right?

I get no errors (probably because the issue is in Hangouts rather than my app so I have nothing to debug there). Logcat shows nothing except an error I can't find much about on Google: `ExternalAccountType﹕ Unsupported attribute readOnly`

The only information I could find on that error implied some issue with permissions but I've made sure my app has runtime permissions checked for Read/Write using this code (which wraps the above):

```
if ((CheckSelfPermission(Permission.ReadExternalStorage) == (int)Permission.Granted) &&
(CheckSelfPermission(Permission.WriteExternalStorage) == (int)Permission.Granted))
```

NOTE: I'm running this on a HTC One M8 - no SD card but does have external storage on device. I've also added the above permissions to the manifest for earlier Android versions.

The documentation for this ([here](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html)) isn't overly helpful either so any advice AT ALL here is welcome :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you use the file provider instead of sending just the URI on its own.  This should get around the permission issues you are seeing.

There is a guide available [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) which might be useful.

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionSend);
shareIntent.SetType("image/gif");

Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory + "/myimage.gif");
Android.Net.Uri fileUri = Android.Support.V4.Content.FileProvider.GetUriForFile(this, "com.myfileprovider", file);

shareIntent.SetPackage("com.google.android.talk");
shareIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
shareIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, fileUri);

StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(shareIntent, "Share with"));
```